# Local Powershell script to trigger VBS script inside Citrix instance

Tags: powershell, citrix, xenapp

I am trying to get a local powershell script to trigger a VBS script inside a citrix instance. The events should be this:

Citrix Instance opening Windows Explorer ----> Network Path of script typed into the windows explorer session

I'm using the WfIcaLib.dll (ICOSDK) that came with the Citrix receiver install. [Documentation PDF for the Citrix ICOSDK is available here](http://www.citrix.com/static/cdn/archivedsdks/icaobjectsdk/ICA_Client_Object_Guide_v10x.pdf)

So this is the code I'm using, which works PERFECTLY in Powershell command line, but when I use the 32-bit ISE, it does nothing other than telling me the DLL has been loaded. I get no errors, but the Citrix Client never actually opens like it does when I run the same exact commands through Powershell command line.

```
#load Citrix ICA Client SDK
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\WfIcaLib.dll")

$ICA = New-Object WFICALib.ICAClientClass 
$ICA.Address = "***.***.***.***:****" 
$ICA.Application = "Windows ExplorerFED6" 
$ICA.Username = "******"
$ICA.Domain = "**" 
$ICA.Launch = $true
$ICA.Outputmode = [WfIcaLib.OutputMode]::OutputModeNormal 
$ICA.SetProp("Password", "*********")
$ICA.TWIMode=$true 
$ICA.Connect()
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: SOLVED - after reopening under 32-bit ISE and getting code to work, I could not run the .ps1 file since it kept defaulting to 64-bit (even if using Open With on 32-bit powershell version). Running the script via command prompt or 32-bit powershell console both worked.

Using any method suggested by Mike Garuccio worked just fine. I will most likely end up using a Task Scheduler to run the script.

Comment: Just want to confirm, what happens if you use the normal 64-bit ISE?  assuming that doesn't work can you run the script in ISE and then run $ICA | Get-Member?  may help to clarify that the object is being created and the correct properties are available.

Comment: Mike, I'm going to have to edit my question now. Right before your comment I got the ISE to run the script, but now if I actually run the saved .ps1 script - I get a runtime exception for each $ICA.Property. It doesn't look like it's loading the DLL. I'm using the x86 (32-bit) version of Powershell to run this (using the Open With menu) and it's throwing errors as if it were the 64-bit instance. - Actually confirmed, I paused the script and looked at the instance, even though I chose the x86 version, it's opening as 64-bit.

Comment: Try opening the 32-bit console and then running the script from there, if that works I can show you how to build a runspace inside your script and run it from there so right-clicking works correctly

Comment: `cd <mydir>`
`.\myscript.ps1` Worked inside my 32-bit powershell. So yes, the script runs fine in 32bit console.

Comment: ok cool, let me go back through my notes and find my stuff on how to configure a runspace for that, answer coming shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is a versioning one, which you can deal with using start-job (was originally going to do this with a runspace but that's a lot more code for no real benefit).  This will start a job to run your code under 32-bit powershell, it should still place any GUI elements or popups on screen but if you need to get any data out from the script later you'll need to receive the job.  code would look something like below.

```
$SB = {
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\WfIcaLib.dll")

  $ICA = New-Object WFICALib.ICAClientClass 
  $ICA.Address = "***.***.***.***:****" 
  $ICA.Application = "Windows ExplorerFED6" 
  $ICA.Username = "******"
  $ICA.Domain = "**" 
  $ICA.Launch = $true
  $ICA.Outputmode = [WfIcaLib.OutputMode]::OutputModeNormal 
  $ICA.SetProp("Password", "*********")
  $ICA.TWIMode=$true 
  $ICA.Connect()
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $SB -RunAs32
get-job | Receive-Job
```

Alternatively, you could also use a simple .bat file as a launcher with something like `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file yourscript.ps1`

or if you need everything to be wrapped in powershell and the job does not work you can use the solution [Here](http://www.powershellserver.com/support/articles/powershell-server-executing-scripts-in-an-x86-runspace/) that basically does the same thing but from within powershell (drop the if statement they use tho, just use the stuff contained inside it like below, with any changes you need to make wrt the profile and interactive settings.)

`&"$env:windir\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noninteractive -noprofile -file "C:\Path    o\script.ps1" -executionpolicy bypass`

hope one of those works for you!

Comment: I was looking at that exact same site and wondering if I even needed the conditional statement. Thanks for the suggestions. Once I discovered you can run powershell through cmd prompt, i realized I can just right a batch script to initiate the powershell. Many options, all work just fine. Appreciate the help!

Comment: yea the conditional only needed if there's a chance your script will be executed on x86 systems(since they don't have a syswow) glad I could help!